# Trying to "blur" a matrix in C++; defective algorithm or code?

Tags: c++, image-processing, matrix, blur

### Issue

I'm trying to "blur" a matrix (as you would an image) using koef (see below) and it's not working the way I want it to. I am providing the matrix via a .txt file.

### What is a koef?

[This site](http://old.cescg.org/CESCG97/boros/index.html) does a great job of explaining how it works. For this blur I am using "Blur Light" with a koef of 14 which is the sum of the following 3x3 matrix (which represents blur densities):

```
1 2 1
2 2 2
1 2 1
```

There's probably an easier way of doing this instead of hardcoding kind of the same thing nine times. I also have hand-drawn diagrams representing the loop/conditional structures and what they're actually doing if that would be useful.

```
void blur(int pic[][MAX_COL]/*OUT*/, int height, int width)
{
    int newPic[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL] = {0};

    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            if (h == 0 && w == 0)
                newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1])
                                /(pic[h][w] + pic[h][w-1] + pic[h+1][w] + pic[h+1][w-1]);
            else if (h == height - 1 && w == width - 1)
                newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 1 * pic[h-1][w-1])
                                /(pic[h][w] + pic[h-1][w] + pic[h][w-1] + pic[h-1][w-1]);
            else if (h == height - 1 && w == 0)
                newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1])
                /(pic[h][w] + pic[h-1][w] + pic[h][w+1] + pic[h-1][w+1]);
            else if (h == 0 && w == width - 1)
                newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1])
                /(pic[h][w] + pic[1][w-1] + pic[h+1][w] + pic[h+1][w-1]);
            else if (h == 0 && (w != 0 && w != width - 1))
                newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1]
                                + 1 * pic[h+1][w+1] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1])/(pic[h][w] + pic[h+1][w] + pic[h-1][w]
                                + pic[h][w+1] + pic[h+1][w+1] + pic[h-1][w+1]);
            else if (w == 0 && (h != 0 && h != height - 1))
                newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w+1]
                                + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1])/(pic[h][w] + pic[h+1][w] + pic[h][w+1] + pic[h][w-1]
                                + pic[h+1][w+1] + pic[h+1][w-1]);
            else if (h == height - 1 && (w != 0 && w != width - 1))
                newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1]
                                + 1 * pic[h-1][w-1])/(pic[h][w] + pic[h+1][w] + pic[h-1][w] + pic[h][w-1]
                                + pic[h+1][w-1] + pic[h-1][w-1]);
            else if (w == width - 1 && (h != 0 && h != height - 1))
                newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1]
                                + 1 * pic[h-1][w-1])/(pic[h][w] + pic[h][w+1] + pic[h][w-1] + pic[h-1][w]
                                + pic[h-1][w+1] + pic[h-1][w-1]);
            else
                newPic[h][w] = (1 * pic[h-1][w-1] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1] + 2 * pic[h][w-1]
                                + 2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 1
                                * pic[h+1][w+1]) / (pic[h][w] + pic[h-1][w-1] + pic[h-1][w] + pic[h-1][w+1]
                                + pic[h][w-1] + pic[h][w+1] + pic[h+1][w-1] + pic[h+1][w]);
        }
    }
    memcpy(pic, newPic, sizeof(newPic));
}
```

**Provided Matrix**

```
10 100 10 100 10 100
10 100 10 100 10 100
100 10 100 10 100 10
100 10 100 10 100 10
```

**Desired Matrix After "Blur"**

```
48 46 64 46 64 61
55 48 61 48 61 55
55 61 48 61 48 55
61 64 46 64 46 48
```

​

**Actual Matrix After "Blur"**

```
2 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

​

---

**Edit:** I have updated my code to reflect two corrections made; the first correction addressed was the [w-1] instead of [w+1] in the first conditional block, and the second correction addressed was dividing by the sum of the densities of neighbors (rather than the sum of the values).

#### Updated Code Block

```
if (h == 0 && w == 0)
  newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 1 * pic[h+1][w+1])/7;
else if (h == height - 1 && w == width - 1)
  newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 1 * pic[h-1][w-1])/7;
else if (h == height - 1 && w == 0)
  newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1])/7;
else if (h == 0 && w == width - 1)
  newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1])/7;
else if (h == 0 && (w != 0 && w != width - 1))
  newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w+1] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1])/10;
else if (w == 0 && (h != 0 && h != height - 1))
  newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w+1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1])/10;
else if (h == height - 1 && (w != 0 && w != width - 1))
  newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1] + 1 * pic[h-1][w-1])/10;
else if (w == width - 1 && (h != 0 && h != height - 1))
  newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1] + 1 * pic[h-1][w-1])/10;
else
  newPic[h][w] = (1 * pic[h-1][w-1] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 1 * pic[h+1][w+1]) / 14;
```

#### Updated Output

```
48  43  34  43  34  61
43  48  61  48  61  43
43  61  48  61  48  43
61  34  43  34  43  48
```

---

**Edit2:** It turns out I'm a massive fool and got my rows and columns flipped around in my head. The following works correctly, thanks again for everyone's help!

#### Updated Code Block

```
// top left corner
if (h == 0 && w == 0)
    newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 1 * pic[h+1][w+1])/7;
// bottom right corner
else if (h == height - 1 && w == width - 1)
    newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 1 * pic[h-1][w-1])/7;
// top right corner
else if (h == height - 1 && w == 0)
    newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1])/7;
// bottom left corner
else if (h == 0 && w == width - 1)
    newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1])/7;
// top edges
else if (h == 0 && (w != 0 && w != width - 1))
    newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w]
                    + 1 * pic[h+1][w+1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1])/10;
// left edges
else if (w == 0 && (h != 0 && h != height - 1))
    newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 1 * pic[h+1][w+1]
                    + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1])/10;
// bottom edges
else if (h == height - 1 && (w != 0 && w != width - 1))
    newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1]
                    + 1 * pic[h-1][w-1])/10;
// right edges
else if (w == width - 1 && (h != 0 && h != height - 1))
    newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1]
                    + 1 * pic[h-1][w-1])/10;
// middle cells
else
    newPic[h][w] = (1 * pic[h-1][w-1] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1] + 2 * pic[h][w-1]
                    + 2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 1
                    * pic[h+1][w+1]) / 14;
```

#### Updated Output

```
48  46  64  46  64  61
55  48  61  48  61  55
55  61  48  61  48  55
61  64  46  64  46  48
```

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the question. You've accepted an answer. That's all that's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normalize (divide) by the sum of the weights, not the sum of the input pixel values (or matrix values if you prefer).

For example the first case would be:

```
newPic[h][w] = (2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w-1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1])
             / (2 + 2 + 2 + 1);
```

Comment: Oh geez, that's such a foolish mistake. Thank you for your help. I changed my code and output above. I am getting a kinda blurred matrix but still not the desired one.

Comment: @koalajesus: Look at each of the elements that are wrong in the output, and double-check your conditions. For example, the case that starts with `w == 0` indexes `[w-1]`.

Comment: @koalajesus: in general, it is easier to add to our running sum under conditions: if w>0, add the elements [w-1], etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're dividing by a number that's too large. For the general case, you should be dividing by 14.

```
else
    newPic[h][w] = (1 * pic[h-1][w-1] + 2 * pic[h-1][w] + 1 * pic[h-1][w+1] + 2 * pic[h][w-1]
    + 2 * pic[h][w] + 2 * pic[h][w+1] + 1 * pic[h+1][w-1] + 2 * pic[h+1][w] + 1
    * pic[h+1][w+1]) / 14;
```

(This is because 14 = 1+2+1+2+2+2+1+2+1)

For the other cases, divide by whatever the sum of the coefficients is for that case.